# How to write rspec for my function?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

```
def get_payment
        @payment   = current_merchant.payments.find_by_id(params[:id]) if params[:id].match(/^(\d)+$/)
        @payment ||= current_merchant.payments.find_by_reference(params[:id])

        raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if @payment.nil?
        @payment
      end
```

I have written the rspec for the code above but it seems unreasonable.I have written the rspec for the code above but it seems unreasonable
Params [: id] contains only integers, and params [: reference] contains both numbers

```
describe "GET show" do
    it "can find payment by id" do
      get :show, id: payment.id
      expect(response).to be_success
      expect(assigns(:payment)).to eq(payment)
    end

    it "can find payment by reference" do
      get :show, id: payment.reference
      expect(response).to be_success
      expect(assigns(:payment)).to eq(payment)
    end
  end
```

Comment: Please explain why you believe it's unreasonable.

Comment: Sorry. It's inconsequential

Comment: I know this is not the question but your code is unnecessarily complicated. You could replace your whole action with `@payment   = current_merchant.payments.where("id = ? OR reference = ?", params[:id], params[:id]).first!`. This will even raise the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` if no payment is found

Comment: thanks, 
So, What about this rspec?

Comment: You're not checking for any of the failure cases. There are a lot of things you can potentially test. It depends on what level of detail you want to achieve in your unit tests.